# character limit of the textbox

Tags: gwt, jsni

I have the textbox and the button and then pass the value in the another textbox. I want that the limit of the second textbox should be 10 and if the limit is exceed beyound the 10 then the{...} should display with the 10 character and if we open that {...}then the whole character that I have type in first textbox will show.The current code that I have worked

```
   public static native void hello()
    /*-{
     var body=$doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
     var text=$doc.createElement("input");
     body.appendChild(text);
     var button=$doc.createElement("button");
     var buttontext=$doc.createTextNode("OK");
     button.appendChild(buttontext);
     body.appendChild(button);
     button.addEventListener("click",function(e)
     {

         var text1=$doc.createElement("input");
         text1.value=text.value;
         body.appendChild(text1);
         if(text1.value.maxlength<10)
         {the character will be shown upto 10 and after that 10 character the {...} will shown and if the {...} will be clicked then the whole character will show.}
         else
         {the character upto the limit 10}


     });
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if I understood you, but maybe this is another approach, based in pure GWT not JSNI:

1. Create to divs one for "..." and another for the textlabel (they can be TextLabel both).
2. On the first div, hide text overflow with css.
3. Add a addKeyDownHandler where you check if you have reached the limit and you make visible the "...". Also, add click handler on it (for showing the full text).
4. If the user clicks on the "..." you show all the text.
5. If you are interested in maintain the same status, check second div when looses focus.